# How to configure Magnific popup

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I have implemented the Magnific popup successfully here:
http://amatoarchitecture.com/new/oakvale-magnific.html

But it appears to be totally un-styled.

How can I set the options for this popup? I would like it to look like this page (this is another plug-in which won't work for complicated reasons):
http://amatoarchitecture.com/new/oakvale.html

I have all the CSS skills needed to change the style of the elements, once they're on the page.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating further, I found that I was actually setting the plug-in up correctly using the configuration instructions in the docs here:
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

There appear to be conflicts with either/both A) existing HTML code, and B) existing Javascript code that prevent the plug-in from functioning correctly in its default form.

I'm going to contact a front-end developer to further troubleshoot this problem, as I don't know the right question to ask here on this site to look for answers here.